# Error al compilar un pacakge con tablas de otro usuario en Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

tengo poca experiencia en PL/SQL y llevo todo el día peleando con el siguiente problema:

tengo 2 usuarios en oracle : U1 y U2. el usuario U1 tiene un package asociado con varios procedimientos, en uno de estos procedimientos se llama a una tabla **(tablaU2 en el ejemplo)** del usuario U2 y al momento de compilar me aparece un error PLS-00201 el identificador 'tablaU2' se debe declarar

```
PROCEDURE procedimientoConError ( variable1 in tabla1.variable1%TYPE,
                                  variable2 in tabla1.variable2%TYPE,
                                  variable3 in tablaU2.variable3%TYPE)
```

PD: hace un par de días funcionaba bien, el problema comenzó cuando (creo) cuando compile el package con el usuario U2 por error.

Gracias de antemano =)

Edit: se me olvido la pregunta xD, alguien sabe como arreglar o a que se debe el problema?

Comment: Hola Dannitt, bienvenido, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 2):

el problema era sencillo, se me reiniciaron los permisos cuando compile el package (del usuario U1) con el usuario U2, por lo que tuve que darle permisos de select y execute al usuario U1 para que el package volviera a compilar y funcionar.